# Index error in loop to separate body of text by speaker in python

Tags: python, nltk

I've got a corpus of text which takes the following form:

> JOHN: Thanks for coming, everyone!
>
> (EVERYONE GRUMBLES)
>
> ROGER: They're really glad to see you, huh?
>
> DAVIS: They're glad to see the both of you.

In order to analyze the text, I want to divide it into chunks, by speaker. I want to retain John and Roger, but not Davis. I also want to find the number of times the certain phrases like (EVERYONE GRUMBLES) occur during each person's speech.

My first thought was to use NLTK, so I imported it and used the following code to remove all the punctuation and tokenize the text, so that each word within the corpus becomes an individual token:

```
f = open("text.txt")
raw_t = f.read()
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw_t.decode('utf-8'))
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
```

Then, I thought that I could create a global list, within which I would include all of the instances of John and Roger speaking.

I figured that I'd first see if each word in the text corpus was upper case and in the list of acceptable names, and if it was, I'd examine every subsequent word until the next incidence of a term that was both upper case and was found in the list of acceptable names. I'd then add all the words from the initial instance of a speaker's name, through to one word less than the next speaker's name, and add this series of tokens/words to my global list.

I've written:

```
k = 0
i = 0
j = 1

names =["JOHN","ROGER"]
global_list =[]

for i in range(len(text)):
    if (text[i].isupper() and text[i] in names):
        for j in range(len(text)-i):
            if (text[i+j].isupper() and text[i+j] in names):
                global_list[k] = text[i:(j-1)]
                k+=1
            else: j+=1
    else: i+=1
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I get the following index error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-97de0c68b674> in <module>()
      6         for j in range(len(text)-i):
      7             if (text[i+j].isupper() and text[i+j] in names):
----> 8                 list_speeches[k] = text[i:(j-1)]
      9                 k+=1
     10             else: j+=1

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I feel like I'm screwing up something really basic here, but am not exactly why I'm getting this index error. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Is there more to your code than this? You haven't initialized k anywhere before using it.

Comment: Something here is inconsistent.  Line 8 in your stack trace differs from the similar line in your source code -- and in the original, it's line 11.

Can you resolve these?  Also, I ran your given text and code, and they complete without error.

Comment: Additionally, what have you done to debug this?  I can almost guarantee that you haven't applied the basic, brute-force technique of sticking in print statements to trace execution.  If you had, I think you'd have noticed that your "if" condition is always false: text[i] is a single character, but you search for it in a list of names.  A single character cannot match either "JOHN" or "ROGER" (... PRUNE comments, passing up the obvious theatrical puns).

Comment: @SahilM yup, just pasted that in. There's some more, but it's largely importing libraries.

Comment: @Prune I'd had to change the text since I was working with text I couldn't post publicly, but the gist — name, punctuation, bracketed responses — are the same. Re: single character for text[i]: that would usually be right, but I don't think I was as clear as I should've been — I'd tokenized everything using NLTK, so text[i] yielded the first word. I've figured out an answer, albeit an inelegant one; about to post it.

Comment: @Prune I just re-read that last sentence in a non sleep-deprived state, and got it a whole lot better. (SROLLEX appreciates the humour, and is grateful for the debugging suggestion, which helped with figuring out why the initial loop was such a mess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out after a bit of digging around. The initial loop mentioned in the question had a whole bunch of extraneous content, so I simplified it to:

```
names =["JOHN","ROGER"]
global_list = []
i = 0

for i in range(len(text)):
    if (text[i].isupper()) and (text[i] in names):
        j=0
        while (text[i+j].islower()) and (text[i+j] not in names):
            j+=1
        global_list.append(text[i:(j-1)])
```

This generated a list, although, problematically, each item in this list was made up of words starting from the name through to the end of the document. Because each item began at the appropriate name while ending at the last word of the text corpus, it was easy to derive the length of each segment by subtracting the length of the following segment from it:

```
x=1
new_list = range(len(global_list)-1)
for x in range(len(global_list)):
    if x == len(global_list):
        new_list[x-1] = global_list[x]
    else:
        new_list[x-1] = global_list[x][:(len(global_list[x])-len(global_list[x+1]))]
```

(x was set to 1 because the original code gave me the first speaker's content twice).

This wasn't in the least bit pretty, but it ended up working. If anyone's got a prettier way of doing it — and I'm sure it exists, since I think I've messed up the initial loop — I'd love to see it.

Comment: You're getting the whole file because your `while` test is always false; `j` is never incremented, so you're effectively copying `text[i:-1]`. But you're making it too hard, use the paragraph breaks as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Break the text into paragraphs with `re.split(r"\n\s*\n", text)`, then examine the first word of each paragraph to see who is speaking. And don't worry about the nltk-- you haven't used it yet, and you don't need to.

Comment: This would've been good, but not every new line has a new speaker — sometimes the crowd reactions interspersed one speaker's phrases. Sorry, should've included that as one of the original examples above!

Comment: That was already clear from your example. I could have been more specific, but I considered it obvious: You can see what kind of paragraph it is (_including_ who is speaking) by examining the first word of each paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I like the idea, but if I split on newline, there's still the question of  figuring out if each subsequent line is a non-name crowd reaction, adding that to that speaker's speech, and then add the following remainder of the speaker's speech to that particular item in the speech list, after which I can resume looking for more names.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much how it would go. And it's a lot simpler than you think, and more reliable than the hoops you're jumping through in your self-answer. But hey, it's your program, you get to choose.